How to time request when other requests are being sent?
I am trying to send a query and a booking request to a server at defined times, both of these are POST requests to an API on the same server. however other users are also doing the same, putting me in a queue and slowing down my response time, and therefore the time I need to send subsequent requests.
My question is the following, is there a way to time or prioritize my request so that I skip the queue or at least get a faster response?
I've tried hosting the script on an EC2 instance which is located in the same datacenter as the server with no avail, I am receiving the response by a delay anywhere from 1s to 6s. Which is too late for the nature of my script. Ideally, my script should not take longer than 1s to execute.
The time it takes to send the request is fairly constant and stable, it takes about 50ms to send any one of my requests.
I've cached the DNS Lookup, SSL and TCP parts of the request. I've also removed unneeded headers and kept the bare minimum headers needed for the API to still return a valid response. Is there something that I can try or experiment with to guarantee faster response times?

If you are competing with other users that are trying to send the requests to the same server, then no there's no way to prioritise. The server's load balancer / application logic can decide where to put you in the queue during high load.
